# Extern in C++ (VS2012) Multiple defined symbols found

Tags: c++

My code is here:

Header.h file:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

extern int k;

#endif /* HEADER_H_ */
```

Source1.h file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;

#ifndef SOURCE1_H_
#define SOURCE1_H_

int k = 10;

void punch(){
    cout << k << endl;
}

#endif /*SOURCE1_H_*/
```

Source.cpp file:

```
#include "Source1.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
punch();
cin.get();
return 0;
};
```

I'm compiling on Visual Studio 2012 express edition in windows 7. The error code is:

```
1>c:\users\freeman\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\exploringexterns\Debug\exploringexterns.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What symbol does the linker say is being multiply defined? Also, please don't use `using namespace std` in a header. Search SO for why this is a bad thing.

Comment: @Praetorian Not having namespace std causes errors, did you mean include it in cpp files and declare  the function in the header/implement in source file?

Comment: @FreemanLou No, I meant qualify your types by typing `std::`. It's not *that* cumbersome to type, and will save you a lot of trouble when you move on to non-trivial projects.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the definition to one and only one source file.

```
int k = 10;
```

By defining the variable in header file you violate the one definition rule because a copy of the variable gets defined in each translation unit where you include the header.

Comment: This is most likely the cause, but from the posted code, it seems there's only one TU (*Source.cpp*)

Comment: Posted code shows the `int k = 10` is in the `source1.h` file. `k`'s declaration needs to be moved to `source1.cpp` file, and in its place in `source1.h` should be the line `extern k;`

Comment: @StarPilot: There is a difference between declaration and definition and you seemed to be confusing the two.

Comment: Why cant I have it in Header.h? Also I thought I has only one definition of int k which is in Source1.h is it defined any where else?

Comment: @Praetorian: Yes. But the error tells otherwise.

Comment: @FreemanLou: It will be defined in each translation unit where you include that header. The code you shows doesn't include it in more than one translation unit but the error you have tells that you do.

Comment: @AlokSave It is an int. Declaring it also defines it, unless you use the keyword `extern` in front of it to make it a declaration only. But yes, I was sloppy in my usage of terminology.

Answer (score 0):

I built this code exactly as you have it without any errors...is there more there?

Potentially, if you have another source file that includes "Source1.h", you would have a problem with this line:

`int k = 10;` in the Source1.h

because then k would be multiply defined. I would move the `int k=10` to Source.cpp

Comment: Its also saying Error 2 error LNK2005: "int k" (?k@@3HA) already defined in Source.obj c:\Users\Freeman\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\exploringexterns\exploringexterns\Source1.obj exploringexterns

Comment: How come it would be defined so many times if the only definition is in Source1.h int k = 10?

Comment: If "Source1.h" is only included by one cpp file in the project (which is what your source says), then it will compile find. The issue is, if there is another source file (cpp) in your project that includes "Source1.h" then you will have the problem. Because of that, it is a bad idea to define variables in header files, it's best to define them in cpp files.

Comment: But, it appears, based on the error, that the code you've posted isn't complete (it compiles fine on VS2012 in Windows 7 for me), or you wouldn't have the error. Is there another file that includes "Source1.h"?

Comment: #David Hope I will create a new project, and see what happens.

Comment: Does anyone know why the Source.obj seem to be staying the same after building everytime?

Comment: Have you done a clean? source.obj will only build if it's changed or been cleaned.

Comment: I've done cleans, but I think the same source obj is still there.

Comment: sounds like your project is screwed up. What happens if you delete it manually?

Comment: Deleting manually works, remade a project and everything succeeds. Why does this happen? Something similar happened in Eclipse juno as well.

Comment: it's hard to say without looking at the bad project file